# Batch Title to Close

Tags: batch-file

After I change the title of a command window via batch file, then I can't close it via batch. Anyone have any thoughts?

I have already tried closing through by using `TASKKILL /F /IM cmd.exe`, but then it closes every batch in my server network, and I don't need it to do that.

Here is the code:

```
:stop

SET /P input=Which server do you want to restart? Do 'ALL' for all:
IF "%input%"=="ALL" (
TASKKILL /F /IM cmd.exe
cd C:\Users\micah_000\Desktop\Server Files\Bungeecord
start Run.bat
cd C:\Users\micah_000\Desktop\Server Files\SG
start Run.bat
cd C:\Users\micah_000\Desktop\Server Files\Hub
start Run.bat
)
```

Comment: I don't think changing the title makes any difference. Did the batch file even exit(maybe the batch file not existing or the issue or part of the issue)?  If you were to remove that changing title line does it suddenly close? What if you changed the title line to some other line does it close? Anyhow,   You can probably always use process explorer to identify the window, then kill that particular window.

Comment: To run multiple MC(Minecraft) servers at once, naming the command windows is essential. Without naming them, discriminating would be hard.

Comment: Hard to help you troubleshoot a batch file when we cannot see the code.

Comment: Maybe, as narzard's answer suggests, your actual question is what command closes a window based on title.  Something you could easily have googled. Obviously you can't close a window via batch file via title if you aren't even trying to find out what the command to do it is and aren't even using a command that comes close to even claiming to do what you want to do.

Comment: It looks like need to see the code in `run.bat`.

Comment: I have a thought: I think this question is still too unclear to answer.  Does ```Run.bat``` actually have anything to do with the question, or is it just part of the scenery?

Comment: @G-Man In the context that he is talking about (running minecraft servers), there would be multiple cmd windows open each given a title based on the servername he is hosting. He wants to programatically kill each server via name... I think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use taskill.

Test Case: Open a command prompt window and type `title sample`

Open a second command prompt and type `taskkill /f /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq sample*"`

This will close the first window and all windows starting with the sample name.

Comment: this is what I have been looking for. I have a perfect usecase for this command. When doing web automation using puppeteer, occasionally puppeteer will fail to connect with a chromium browser, and there is no programmatic way to close the orphaned browser instance. Fortunately, the browser window has a distinct title of "about:blank - Chromium". This cmd can perfectly clean up the mess.

Comment: Great idea! I think they should build a similar functionality into Puppeteer. Seems to happen often enough.